# Checking password length problem for registration in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, passwords

I'm trying to write a base user registration page and my problem is on checking `password` length string. I've read of various problem and solutions on that but I still in troubles.

This is what I've wrote:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    function register () {
        if (!empty ($this->data)) {
            if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password_confirm'])) {
                if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('All ok');
                    $this->redirect(array('action', 'login'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Password mismatch');
                $this->redirect(array('action', 'register'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the user model:

```
var $validate = array (
    'username' => array (
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Alphanumeric chars only'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 24),
            'message' => 'Username between 1 and 24 chars'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array (
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 7, 25),
            'message' => 'Password between 8 and 24 chars'
        )
    )
);
```

File `register.ctp`

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->end('Register account');
?>
```

The password and password_confirm checking works perfect, if I write different passwords I get the error, if the password are equal, I get a password length error, where I'm wrong?

log:

```
2011-03-29 23:20:41 Error: Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [username] => tonino
        [password] => ae4f47749b697085b2f7322383fa7b14c79e06f6
        [password_confirm] => passwordtest
    )

)
```

I've forgot to say my password is `SHA1 hashed`, so how I can check if an user write a too long password?

Comment: What do you show if you do $this->log($this->data) before calling $this->User->save()

Comment: I've wrote the log in the question. thanks for the tip, it's useful for debug!

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are hashed automatically by the AuthComponent. All the validation you're doing is done on the password `"ae4f47749b697085b2f7322383fa7b14c79e06f6"`, not `"passwordtest"`, which is why it fails validation. You need to do the validation on the `password_confirm` field, not the `password` field.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760663/cakephp-password-validation/3760832#3760832) for an example of a somewhat transparent solution.