# Checking whether a user is logged in

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a cake php 2.0 program with a change password facility.  Before a user changes their password I want them to reconfirm their password.  What is the best way to do this in Cake?  Let's say I have two variables in my `UserController` class called `$username` and `$password`....

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this URL's for the information:-

[change_password](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/models/behaviors/change_password.php)

[CakePHP login form with password confirmation using Auth component](http://blog.boogly.net/2009/12/cakephp-login-form-with-password-confirmation-using-auth-component/)

[cakephp password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760663/cakephp-password-validation)

[password](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1263/password)

Comment: for the first link I could only add the documentation on it: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ as well as the correct 2.0 branch for him: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Model/Behavior/ChangePasswordBehavior.php